# Manually start and stop CRON on OS X

Tags: php, terminal, cron

I would like to be able to test a server side process in my local dev env using a CRON task that runs every minute. However I do not want this to run every minute of every day, just when I need to test the process.

Is there some Terminal command I can use to add a CRON task and another to do the reverse (remove it).

Ideally I'd then like to execute this command via a tool like [Shuttle](https://github.com/fitztrev/shuttle) so that I can start/stop the CRON from the taskbar as and when required.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end I abandoned this idea and used an app called CronniX to manually start and stop a local CRON process:

https://code.google.com/p/cronnix/

Comment: How did you start/stop within CronniX? I only see the option to change the crontab entries. I assume you mean disable them and save.

Comment: This only edits the crontab which can easily be done using terminal command `env EDITOR=nano crontab -e`, it doesn't stop a currently running cron job